# Technical considerations aside, could I legally purchase three CCBs from ULA and build my own Atlas V Heavy?

Tags: law, ula, atlas-v

We all know and mourn that the Atlas V will never fly in a three-core configuration. What, if anything, prevents me from legally purchasing three CCBs and launching my own Atlas V Heavy, provided I have access to some unused chunk of Cape Canaveral coastline upon which to build the required assembly and launch infrastructure?

Comment: Are you [ITAR Certified?](https://www.ftptoday.com/blog/what-are-itar-certification-requirements)

Comment: This question is a little odd as written. If you're just asking "what does an entity need to do, legally, to be able to buy, modify, and launch medium-lift orbital rockets," then you should ask that without the baggage of the Atlas V Heavy as part of the question.

Comment: This seems to be more a question for a legal forum than for a technical forum.